# How to use wraptable with llncs format?

Tags: wrap, lncs

I have to use `llncs` format: [example here](https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS).

I'm trying to wrap a simple table. Here's my syntax:

```
this is some sample text, blah blah blah 
\begin{wraptable}%{r}{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{table title here}}\\
    \toprule    
    \textbf{A} & b\\
    \textbf{C} & d \\
    \textbf{E} & f\\
    \bottomrule
    \label{tab}
    \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 
more text here blah blah lhabladfl blha blha blah
```

but this only wraps one line around the table:

[image]

I'm using `llncs` format which breaks if I use `\usepackage{wrapfig}`, so currently I'm not importing that package.

Also, if I use `begin{wraptable}{r}{0.35\textwidth}`, then the `r0.35extwidth` appears as text in the paper just before the table!

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: `llncs` is compatible with `wrapfig`, see my answer below. If you still experience problems, please post a *complete* document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Something may be wrong, but it is not the combination `llncs`+`wrapfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`llncs` doesn't appear to define an environment called `wraptable`, did you not get an error? The image you show is consistent with just putting a `tabular` (acting as an oversized letter in the middle of a paragraph, the text isn't wrapping at all, the table is just in the main paragraph flow.

Never ignore TeX errors, the pdf produced after an error is at best useful as a debugging aid, TeX's error recovery is not intended to produce usable output.

Comment: The example link I was following added many packages as had I. Not sure which packages were causing problems, but i started from scratch adding only the packages i needed and it worked w/o errors. I did have to add \usepackage{wrapfig}.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why the `llncs` format breaks when using `wrapfig`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{wrapfig,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{wraptable}{r}{0.35\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{table title here}}\\
    \toprule    
    \textbf{A} & b\\
    \textbf{C} & d\\
    \textbf{E} & f\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{wraptable} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```